# как можно вывести индексы максимумов и минимумов в матрице?

Tags: java, массивы

Создать программу, которая вводит c клавиатуры двумерный массив неотрицательных целых чисел, находит минимум из максимальных элементов каждой строки и выводит на экран этот минимум, все максимальные элементы строк, их местоположение в первоначальном массиве и число попыток ввести отрицательный элемент.

```
package com.example.mas;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class arr7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int[][] a = {{4, 3, 2, 1},
            {6, 7, 8, 9},
            {11, 12, 10, 13},
            {14, 16, 15, 17}};
         int [] b = new int [a[0].length];

         for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
             int max = a[i][0];
             max1 = a[i][1];
             int i_max = 0;
             int j_max = 0;
             int i_max1 = 0;
             int j_max1 = 0;
             for (int element : a[i]) {
                 if (element > max) {
                     max = element;
                     i_max = i;
                 }
             }
             if (max < max1) {
                max1 = max;
             }
             System.out.print(max1 +" ");
             System.out.println(max+" ");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: @walentina, в вашем коде нет ничего, что могло бы приблизить вас к решению вашей задачи. Не знаю зачем было это написано. Как будто просто заглушка для того, чтобы не кидали помидоров за то, что нужно сделать все за вас. Не красиво...

Answer (score 1):

> как можно вывести индексы максимумов и минимумов в матрице?

Необходимо пройти по матрице с помощью 2х циклов внешний идет по строкам, внутренний по столбцам
так же необходимо завести буферные переменные: максимумы строк (от реализации зависит, но пусть пока int maxs[a.length]), кол-во попыток отрицательного ввода (int count)
в каждой строке перед началом внутреннего цикла присваиваем первый элемент строки maxs[i], после чего проходя по строке сравниваем с этим элементом текущий и если элемент строки больше эл-та массива, пишем в массив больший элемент, кроме того сравниваем эл-т с 0 и если он меньше то count++, так же пишем какие то данные которые вам необходимы в ваш буфер

после выхода из циклов находим в maxs минимум